# Keeping Window "Docked" In Same Place C#/Wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm working on a windows wpf app to do fluid modeling using an open source engine called epanet.  There is already an open source UI written in Pascal, we are trying to create one like it with added features and usability.

I want the app to start and have a main window with a couple tool bars and 2 separate sub-windows inside, as in the original epanet UI software (take a look at some of the screen shots in the link below).  What is the best way to go about this?

http://engineering.wayne.edu/wsuwater/hydraulics/epanet.php

I tried using "popup" from this forum post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/bf51e572-b41e-487b-99d0-95262899ef2c/

It was far to finicky and hard to control.  Instead, I just created a new window and had it open after the MainWindow() class is loaded.

`InitializeComponent(); 
DrawingArea Init_Canvas = new DrawingArea();
Init_Canvas.Show();`

This works great, other than that the user has to manually adjust it to the right size and placement every time.

How do I go about getting it stay tidily tucked in the corner?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive I understand the question but it seems like you need to display controls on top of one another.  I too ran into problems with popups too and used this code as an alternative:

```
<Grid>
<Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
  <TextBlock FontSize="55">One</TextBlock>
</Canvas>
<Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
  <TextBlock FontSize="55">Two</TextBlock>
</Canvas>

</Grid>
```

Basically you set both controls to be row=0 and column=0 and they will display on top of one another.  Maybe this doesn't meet your needs, but it is a nice trick.